# How to use mongoose native promise (mpromise) to remove a document and then update another document

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, promise

I am trying to use promises to avoid deep nested callbacks. I have the following code:

```
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
  var actionID = req.body.id;

  var promise = Action.findById(actionID).exec();
  promise.then(function (action) {
    return Action.remove({'_id': action.id}).exec();
  }).then(function (count, action, something) {
    debugger;
  });
};
```

My action document Schema contains and array of ObjectIDs referencing child actions:

```
var ActionSchema = new Schema({
  title: String, // Text to be shown when creating new action
  description: String, // Description if any
  children: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], default: [] }, // JSON.stringified list of children
  nest_level: Number, // how nested we are for children level
});
```

What I'm trying to do is remove an action document, when that's done and successful, look for all action documents associated with the deleted action (via children field), and remove the deleted action's ObjectID from the 'children' array.

In the debugger section, count gives back the number of deleted documents, action seems to be an empty string, and nothing else is returned (the 'something' variable is undefined).

I have two questions:

- How do I go about resolving or rejecting the promise in a mongoose promise? There isn't much information on the internet to follow (usually it's a general promise tutorial).
- If Action.remove().exec() doesn't return a copy of the removed document, how would I do another query to actually update other documents?

Comment: What do you expect `action` and `something` to be?

Comment: You don't resolve or reject mongoose promises. They are fulfilled/rejected when the query that you executed succeeded/failed.

Comment: action and something were placeholders, I was expecting a copy of the removed document to be returned, and 'something' to have been an error (or they might have been switched).

Comment: To be fair mpromise is one of the most terrible implementations of promises/A+, you're probably even better off with native promises if you can use those.

Comment: Upon reading some reviews on mpromise, I'm beginning to regret my decision to go down this route. Maybe I'll npm a better one.

Comment: @PGT it's entirely possible to use regular/better promises with mongoose. For example you can do `var Promise = require("bluebird"); var Mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));` which adds `Async` versions of methods that return bluebird promises which are a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`findByIdAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) to simplify the first step (why make two db requests?). If successful the resolved promise will be the removed document.

```
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
  var actionID = req.body.id;

  Action.findByIdAndRemove(actionID).exec().then(function(action) {
    // action.children 
  }).then(null, function(err) {
    // Do something with the error.
  });
};
```

From there you would need to manage the removal of the actions from the children list. Solutions for doing this include [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or if you just want to continue using promises (you don't care about managing the load if there are a lot of children or recursively removing children) you could use the built in [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object available in newer releases of node.

```
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
  var actionID = req.body.id;

  Action.findByIdAndRemove(actionID).exec().then(function(action) {
    return Promise.all(action.children.map(function(id) {
      Action.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
    })); // returns promise
  }).then(function (results) {
    // results will be an array of child docs removed.
    // NOTE: this isn't recursive
  }).then(null, function(err) {
    // Do something with the error.
  });
};
```

To make it recursive (again without load management) would take a bit of refactoring. Something like:

```
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
  destroy(req.body.id).then(function (results) {
    // results will be a multi-dimesional array if children are removed
    // response
  }).then(null, function (err) {
    // error response
  });
};

function destroy(actionID) {
  return Action.findByIdAndRemove(actionID).exec().then(function(action) {
    return Promise.all(action.children.map(function(id) {
      return destroy(id);
    })); // returns promise
  });
}
```

*Note: none of this code has been tested*